# Image not getting retrieved in android app. Only image name is getting displayed

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I tried to retrieve a table data stored in Mysql database and i got only the text fields displayed. The image is stored in the table through form submission.

But when data is retrieved the image is not getting displayed. Instead only name of the image appears in the result.

```
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
$uid  = $_GET['uid'];

$sql = "select * from wpt5_driver_trial where uid like '%$uid%'";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    array_push($result,array('uid'=>$row[1],
    'id'=>$row[2],
    'name'=>$row[3],
    'posting'=>$row[4],
    //'file'=>$row[5] 
   'file'=>'<img src="data:uploadImages/jpeg;base64.base64_encode($row[5]).' "height="100" width="100" />'
    ));
}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: question is for php or Android ?

Comment: Missing , after base64?

Comment: you have syntax error first please fix it. Than try to run your code. update your line starts with `'file'` like this : `'file'=>'<img src=\"data:uploadImages/jpeg;base64'.base64_encode($row[5]).'\" style=\"height: 100; width=100; \"/>'`

Comment: I tried the code @ Ergin Ersoy.... But still the image is not getting displayed. @Vivek Mishra I'm not sure about the path i had given for image is correct in PHP code. this code is called in android app

Comment: what is the result when you called from android ?

Comment: i'm getting only text fields and not an image view. Instead getting image holder and image name alone. @Ergin Ersoy